# Navbar-Fixed responsive navbar

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to implement a navbar and I want to position several elements in three different positions (align left, right and center).

The left is by default, but I can't make  the elements in the center, and in the right(for log in and log out) on the screen, can someone help me solve my problem and understand what I need to add?

Is a responsive Navabr only with HTML and CSS.

Thanks!

**HTML and CSS**

```css
.menu .left{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

.nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
    text-align: right;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
 }

.menu {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0; 
}

.menu a {
    clear: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 70px;
    
}

span {
    color: #191970;
}

label {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: none;
    width: 26px;
    float: right;
}

#toggle {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .menu {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }

    .menu a {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
        margin: 0;    
    }

    #toggle:checked + .menu {
        display: block;
    }
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
      <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
    
      <div class="menu" >
      
        <a href="#"  ><i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i><span >Appel-Lib</span></a>
     
     
        <a href="/home"  routerLink="home">
          <i class="fa fa-hospital-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Home</a>
        
        <a href="/admin"   *ngIf="showAdminBoard"  routerLink="admin">
          <i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           Admin Board </a>

        <a href="/mod" *ngIf="showModeratorBoard"  routerLink="mod">Moderator Board</a>
        <a href="/user"  *ngIf="isLoggedIn" routerLink="user">
          <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          User</a>

        <a href="/register" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" routerLink="register">
          <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>

          Sign Up</a>   

        <a href="/signuppatient" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" routerLink="signuppatient">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           Patient</a>

        <a href="/login" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" routerLink="login">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>
          Login
        </a>
        <a href="/profile" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" routerLink="profile">{{ username }}</a>
        <a href  *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="logout()">
          <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          LogOut</a>
  
          
      </div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Comment: It seems you have a lot more than 3 elements, so how exactly are you going to position them left center and right? Are they in groups?

Comment: yeah I have more than three, not in groups

Comment: So which ones should be left, right and center exactly?

Comment: left (Appel-Lib & home)  right ( Sign Up & log in & logOut) the others in the center

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to put the specific links into to Ul and Li. For example, for the right group you should put:

```html
<ul class="right-group">
   <li>
      <a href="/register" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" routerLink="register">
         <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Sign Up</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="/login" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" routerLink="login">
         <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>
      Login</a>
   </li>
   <li>
        <a href  *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="logout()">
          <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        LogOut</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then what you should do is style the ul:

```css
.right-group {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
   height: /* the height of your navbar */;
   width: 100%;
   justify-content: right; /* this should change depending on where you want your group to be (ex: left, right, center) */
   list-style: none;
}
```

That should work if you are asking what I think your asking. The fact that you have a lot of links might change what the result might be like, so keep that in mind.

Comment: it doesn't matter how many link if it works for two (separate the left and the right) it will work for all

Comment: Yeah, but I was saying that the amount of links you have might put your links on a separate line, depending on the screen size.

Comment: I will run my code into codepen and then try to fix it.